# Make a queue of images on view before upload in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to upload multiple files in database in **MVC**. But before saving the images in server folder, I want to make a **list of images on view** by selecting images from different folders on client machine. *It is possible to upload multiple images using file type input*.

But I want to use **same file type input** to make a collection of images from different locations on my machine and then upload the collection **on button click**. How to do this?

Comment: before upload the multiple files, I want to make a collection of images from different location and show the list on view where user can remove or add more images to collection. After that on button click I want to save the images with other data on view.

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. Check out the jquery file upload  plugin: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/